# android xml design is showing more space at the bottom of screen in larger screen devices like > 6.0 inches especially in Samsung M20

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

i'm using `RelativeLayout` in Home screen xml design.
inside it `CustomScrollView` with in that showing a `RecyclerView`.
it is working fine with normal screen devices showing/fixed with screen size, but with Larger screen devices like Samsung M20 Phones, it is showing extra space in-between the `Recyclerview` and `BottomView`
 Please Observe the below screenshot :
[image]

Here is XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp.util.CustomScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rr_profileView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card_notification"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_clubNews"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:src="@drawable/clun_news3" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:background="@drawable/text_cta"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_all"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_regular"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_20" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_clubNews"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/card_notification">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ClubNewsTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_texts"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_regular"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_18" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ClubNewsDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_texts"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_regular"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_ClubNewsTitle"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp.custom.MyRecycler
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/colorgbGrey"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDividerGrey" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorLightWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sendUsFeedback"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#3D3D3D"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_regular"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
                    android:text="Send Us feedback" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp.util.CustomScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
            android:background="@color/colorLightWhite" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rr_sendfeedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v_toolbar"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/include_sendus_feed" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me, how to resolve this type of design issues.
All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks You.!

Comment: The child content of scrollview has always a `wrap_content` height instead of `match_parent`

Comment: Yes. Set height to `wrap_content` for `CustomScrollView` and Child `LinearLayout` might fix the issue.

Comment: still exists the space. now space showing after the footerview

Comment: try changing the com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp.custom.MyRecycler height to "wrap_content" and removing the weight

Comment: still exists, space given after the footerview now